# Nonvanishing of Dirichlet Series on Re(s)=1

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I am reading a proof of Prime numbers in Dirichlet arithmetic progressions via this link: http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~evertse/ant14-7.pdf

However, according to his lemma 7.6, the writer wanted to make sure that $L(1+it,\chi)\ne0$ for all characters mod $q$. So he used theorem 5.5 which can be seen in this link http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~evertse/ant14-5.pdf) stating that $L(1+it,\chi) \ne 0$ for all $\chi^2\ne\chi_0$ where $\chi_0$ is the principal character mod $q$.

My problem is, for characters mod 4 which consist of $\chi_0, \chi_1$ , how he could make sure that $L(1+it,\chi_0)$ and $L(1+it,\chi_1)$ are not $0$? This is because $\chi_1^2 =\chi_0$. That means we cannot use theorem 5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historically, the case of real quadratic characters are the most difficult, and stumped many people for a very long time. Now there is a huge variety of known approaches, some even almost completely combinatorial.

In this document, you should just read one sentence further, when the author explains that he has yet to handle real quadratic characters. Then lemma 5.6 sets up theorem 5.7, which contains the proof for the real quadratic case.

Comment: Thank you @mixedmath. According to the document, I understand that his theorem 5.7 is responsible for only the case when $s=1$ not $1+it$.

Comment: @user110706: Then read 5.5 closer. It shows the case when $s = 1 + it$ for all characters, without restriction on real quadratics (and it shows $s = 1$ for non-real quadratic characters)

Comment: I am so sorry. I may be confused. Yet, I understand that theorem 5.5 can be applied provided that $\chi^2\ne\chi_0$ not for any character.

Comment: @user110706: He says *Assume **either** that $t\neq 0$, or that $t = 0$ and $\chi^2 \neq 1$*. You are missing the **either**, it seems